# How do I add a custom CSS file?

Tags: magento2, css

In Magento 2 I have a custom theme and in the layout folder `layout>default_head_blocks.xml` which contains the css link.

The css file is contained in `web>css>customcss.css` - but the file is not linking

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have path like this:

```
\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml
```

Then put the content like following in your default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/customcss.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

To add the external CSS or CDN you can use the following

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="css/customcss.css" />
            <css src="http://cdn.test.com/extra.css" src_type="url"/>
            <script src="http://cdn.test.com/extra.js" src_type="url"/>
        </head>
    </page>
```

And I assume your customcss.css file as following path  :

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\customcss.css
```

After doing so you've to clear your cache using following commands

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

> Note: Every Time you've to flush cache unless you are using Gulp/Grunt.

Let me know if you facing any problem.

Comment: perfect answer with explanation!!! +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Just add new file here

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\_new.less
```

and import this file in source file given path below

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\_sources.less
```

import your file

(if there is not available _source.less file in your theme then go to 'vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source' folder and copy file in your custom theme)

```
@import '_new.less';
```

1. clear cache
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 3):

you can using this code below in your layout:

```
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
```

You have to delete folders

> pub/static
>
> var/

deploy static content using command
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

check you css changes.

Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout's file `default_head_blocks.xml` inside `<head>` tag add

```
<css src="css/customcss.css"/>
```

You might need to delete folders `pub/static`, `var/page_cache`, `var/view_preprocessed`  deploy static content using command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to make your css file effective.

Comment: If you delete the .htaccess file in pub/static you have to copy that from fresh installation. Otherwise it breaks frontend.

Answer (score 0):

**Add below code in default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<css src="css/custom.css"/>
```

**but you need to add less file in your theme dir. under the web/css dir**

```
create custom.less
In custom.less file file import all less files as per your requirment.
```

**magento\dev\tools\grunt\configs\theme.js**

```
    open theme.js file and add your less file under the theme
    Make sure don't give extenstion when you add file.

**For Example**
alive: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Alive/alivetheme',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/custom'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```